# samba how to display files with colon in their names?

Tags: samba

Samba does not display files correctly when they contain a colon.

Original file name: `test:file.txt`

Display name under Windows: `T8S6CH~R.TXT`

How can I fix it?

**Info:**

Linux: `SLES 11 SP 3`

Samba: `Version 3.6.3-0.33.39.1-3128-SUSE-CODE11-x86_64`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason Samba started to mangle the file names containing a colon. That far I could not find anything regarding this behavior in Internet.

The solution is very simple. Adding `mangled names = no` in the `[global]` section to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and restarting Samba fixed the issue.

Comment: Great to know that! +1

Comment: This solution is incomplete.  Files with illegal Windows characters such as ':' are not shown.  See roaima's solution.

Answer (score 25):

The problem with Samba's `mangled names` option is that neither setting is ideal. You can have names that are not mangled, but cannot be accessed in any way because they contain illegal characters, or names that are mangled into the DOS 8.3 format and hence close to unreadable.

Fortunately there is (now) a [VFS module called `catia`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_catia.8.html) which will provide custom character mappings. In particular it's possible to map out the characters considered illegal in Windows filenames.

In the `[global]` section place these lines:

```
    # Mapping illegal characters, where enabled with "vfs objects = catia"
    mangled names = no
    catia:mappings = 0x22:0xa8,0x2a:0xa4,0x2f:0xf8,0x3a:0xf7,0x3c:0xab,0x3e:0xbb,0x3f:0xbf,0x5c:0xff,0x7c:0xa6
```

In each `[share_name]` section add this next line (if you already have a `vfs objects` line, just append `catia` to the list):

```
    vfs objects = catia
```

As usual, if it's going to apply to all your shares, this share-based setting can be placed in `[global]` instead of each individual share defintion.

On my Debian-based system this VFS object module was installed as part of the standard package.

One example of a filename that is mapped by this setting is `2017-12-24 12:23.txt`. Using `mangled names = yes` has this file displayed as `2BB0Y9~4.TXT`. Using `vfs objects = catia` instead has this file name displayed as `2017-12-24 12÷23.txt`. It's not perfect but it's pretty good. And most importantly, I can access it from Windows applications.

Comment: See ⁚ ∶ ׃  ꞉ for other characters that look like ASCII colon.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas please do also feel free to submit that as a suggestion to the Samba development team. I just took their suggested list.

Comment: When I share a folder with Nautilus, the folder does not, obviously, show up in /etc/samba/smb.conf.  How can I apply your solution in this scenario?

Comment: Here is another map I came up with, that uses more characters from the General Punctuation and Mathematical Operators plane: `0x22:0x201f,0x2a:0x2217,0x2f:0x2215,0x3a:0x2236,0x3c:0x2039,0x3e:0x203a,0x3f:0xbf,0x5c:0x2216,0x7c:0x2223`

Answer (score 2):

Special characters question mark ? \ < > * etc are illegal in windows filenames and I always avoid using them.

Nevertheless, I have ***no problem* with these characters using my *macOS*** Catalina accessing my FreeNAS-11.3-U1 and SMB/Samba setup. I'm not sure why this setting isn't by default, but you'll have to follow these steps to make it work flawless with MacOS.

In FreeNAS webUI, goto Sharing>SMB>Edit

1. Choose "advanced mode" and checkmark both ***catia*** and ***fruit*** in "VFS objects"
2. Set auxiliary parameter to `fruit:encoding = native`

Then goto Services and restart SMB

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users wanting to mount Samba volumes hosted on Linux without messed-up characters & filenames:

A snippet from my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[sharename]
path = /path/to/share
browsable = yes
writable = yes
valid users = nick
create mask = 644
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:encoding = native
```

I had to add the last 3 lines in the config above  to get filenames with characters like `?` to map properly between Mac & Linux.

Don't forget to restart your Samba service after changes eg `sudo service smbd restart`

(This is expanding on the suggestion by @trommegutten with some text for `smb.conf` rather than FreeNAS settings)

Comment: Your answer is for mac users, which is not what OP was asking.

Comment: Sure, I get that it was not asked by the OP but the same odd-name problem can happen on Mac (that's how I ended up here), so I figured worth noting that.