# mkdir "No such file or directory" within a directory that exists

Tags: directory, samba, mkdir

I have a network (samba) share mounted at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=wdmycloud,share=family`. Most activities work fine within the share - I can move stuff around, create and delete files, etc. However, if I `cd` into `Music/Various Artists` (both of which definitely exist) and try to create a specific directory, it fails:

```
$ mkdir "Pretty in Pink: The Original Motion Picture Soundtrack"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Pretty in Pink: The Original Motion Picture Soundtrack’: No such file or directory
```

`mkdir -p` also fails:

```
$ mkdir -p "Pretty in Pink: The Original Motion Picture Soundtrack"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Pretty in Pink: The Original Motion Picture Soundtrack’: No such file or directory
```

However, `mkdir` functions fine for other directory names:

```
$ mkdir test
# no output, directory created
```

What's special about the name `Pretty in Pink: The Original Motion Picture Soundtrack` that `mkdir` chokes on it? How can I get around this issue?

*Please don't judge me for the music, I'm doing this for someone else...*

Comment: What's wrong with the music? :-) If you really want those colons have a read of the `mangled names` option and the `catia` module for Samba. [samba how to display files with colon in their names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381639/100397)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colons aren’t valid characters on SMB/CIFS shares — Windows uses them for drive letters. The failing directory name contains one, which is why `mkdir` fails.

Comment: ... yep. Cool and bad. Good thing this drive has an FTP frontend as well.

Comment: @c-x-berger if you create a filename containing a colon then you won't be able to see it across the Samba share unless you've either `mangled names = yes` (horrible) or you've enabled `catia` and are happy for the colon to be rewritten as a similar-but-different character

Comment: @roaima unfortunately, the Samba share is hosted by a consumer-grade network drive that I can't really configure that much. However, it presents other frontends (FTP, NFS, etc) that actually work and I don't think these files need to be accessed by anything besides a Linux HTPC.

Comment: Samba won't show "illegal" file names without the catia module enabled

Comment: Right, but I can use FTP or something for accessing it instead, and since the only client(s) I expect are running Linux, the mangled names shown by Samba aren't an issue.

Comment: I’d say NFS would be a better replacement, at least you could mount your storage in a similar manner to what you have now.