# Script to change file/folder names which contain illegal characters (Synology NAS)

Tags: linux, scripting, synology

We have an issue where a set of data that was migrated from an old DAS drive which was attached to a Mac Mini acting as a server contains many illegal folder names (namely colons :). Some of the users must have created these and although the NAS allowed me to migrate them and they show up ok from the Synology's in built file browser, when accessing them from a Windows or Mac based client the folder names have been replaced with a auto-generated unique folder name.

I'm no Linux expert by any stretch of the imagination so I wonder if somebody could please help me out with a script that will remove the : (colon) from these folders so their Mac based machines are able to see them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [samba how to display files with colon in their names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299130/samba-how-to-display-files-with-colon-in-their-names)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the `:` that is causing trouble, you could use `find` with `rename` option to replace that character with something else.

```
find /path/to/share -name "*:*" -exec rename 's/\:/_/' {} \;
```

Note that I haven't tested this, so try it on sample data first.

Comment: This should use `+` instead of `\;`, so that it only executes `rename` once per (ARG_MAX - env size) characters worth of filenames, instead of once per filename.  Alternatively, instead of `-exec rename ...`, use `-print0` and pipe find's output into `rename -0 's/:/_/g'` (but note that some old versions of perl rename don't support the `-0` option, read the man page or run `rename --help`).

Comment: BTW, `rename` won't replace existing files unless you force it to with `-f` or `--force` ... so if `rename` outputs any **old_filename not renamed: new_filename already exists** warnings, you can just run it again with `s/:/__/g` (and again with `s/:/___/g`, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

If `bash` is available on that system:

```
LC_ALL=C find /path/to/share -depth -name '*:*' -type d -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    base=${file##*/}
    mv -i "$file" "${file%/*}${base//:}"
  done' bash {} +
```

Should remove the `:`s in the names of directories.

If `bash` is not available, but `mksh` (MirBSD shell, and also the shell of Android) or `ksh93` is (that `${var//pattern/replacement}` operator is actually from ksh93), that should also work if you replace `bash` with `ksh` above. Same with `zsh`.

Beware that if both  `/path/to/share/foo:bar` and `/path/to/share/foobar` directories exist, `mv -i /path/to/share/foo:bar /path/to/share/foobar` will actually move `foo:bar` into `foobar`. With the GNU implementation of `mv`, that can be avoided by passing the `-T` option to `mv` in which case you will get (thanks to `-i`) a `mv: overwrite '/path/to/share/foobar'?` prompt instead, and if you answer yes and `foobar` was empty, `foo:bar` will be renamed to `foobar` (and the old `foobar` discarded).